# How to add an Hotmail account to Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I use Windows 7 and Microsoft Office 2007. I am trying to add an Hotmail account in my Outlook 2007.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You're question is vague.  Loose the fluff, post your question with specific details. How did you try to add the account?  What if any error messages did you receive?  What were you expecting to happen and what actually happened?  Adding focused information on your question increases the likelihood that you will get helpful answers.

Answer (score 5):

You first have to install [Microsoft Office Outlook Connector for Windows Live Hotmail](http://office.microsoft.com/search/redir.aspx?AssetID=XT102249071033&CTT=5&Origin=HA102218231033).

See [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA102218231033.aspx) for more information.

Comment: This is the easiest and most pain free way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[Use a Windows Live Hotmail account in Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA102218231033.aspx)
<sup><sub>Applies to: Microsoft Office Outlook 2007, Outlook 2003</sub></sup>

Comment: You're guide gives essentially the same answer as fretje, as they mention the Outlook Connector ;-) Had you paraphrased the steps from the link, you would have gotten my upvote!

Comment: @Ivo - It was fretje that gave the same answer as me. My answer was  given one hour before his.

Comment: I meant that you should have added the steps, then it would have been better ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hotmail Incoming mailserver(POP3): **pop3.live.com** (logon using Secure Password Authentification - SPA, mail server port: 995)

Hotmail Outgoing mailserver(SMTP): **smtp.live.com** (SSL enabled, port 25)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you were asking for, but I import all my Hotmail in my Gmail.

Advantages:

- You get a way better way to access Hotmail online (through Gmail)
- You get a much better search function (Google hello?)
- You only have to set-up one e-mail in Outlook (if you have both) with the use of "3rd" party tools like Outlook connector